# Sudden Drop in fps after rendering a font

Tags: java, performance, libgdx, frame-rate

So I am working in this simple side scrolling game like flappy bird and the game ran smoothly when I added the music and all the sprites.But when I added font(ttf) to it the game had an abrupt drop in fps and it lagged a lot.
Any help please?

Here is my render method:

```
 @Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {

    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(actualGamebg, cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth/2), 0);
    sb.draw(bird.getTexture(), bird.getPosition().x , bird.getPosition().y);
    for(Tube tube: tubes) {

        sb.draw(tube.getTopTube(), tube.getPosTopTube().x, tube.getPosTopTube().y);
        sb.draw(tube.getBottomTube(), tube.getPosBottomTube().x, tube.getPosBottomTube().y);
    }
    sb.draw(ground,groundPos1.x,groundPos1.y);
    sb.draw(ground,groundPos2.x,groundPos2.y);

    font24.draw(sb,SCORE,24,100);
    sb.end();

}
```

My full playstate class is:

```
package com.maharshmangal.game.State;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;
import com.maharshmangal.game.FlappyDemo;
import com.maharshmangal.game.Sprites.Bird;
import com.maharshmangal.game.Sprites.Tube;

import java.util.Timer;

/**
 * Created by Kronos on 28-12-2016.
 */

public class PlayState extends State {
    private static final int TUBE_SPACING = 100;
    private static final int TUBE_COUNT = 4;


    private Bird bird;
    private Texture actualGamebg;
    private Tube tube ;
    private Texture ground;
    private Vector2 groundPos1,groundPos2;
    private static final int HIGHEST_GROUND_LIMIT = -30;
    private Array<Tube> tubes;
    private int k;
    long startTime=0;
    private Music mainMusic;
    private Music scoreIncrease;
    private Music wingFlap;
    public BitmapFont font24;
    public String SCORE;






    public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
        bird = new Bird(0,300);
        actualGamebg = new Texture("bg.png");
        cam.setToOrtho(false, FlappyDemo.WIDTH/2,FlappyDemo.HEIGHT/2);

        tubes =new Array<Tube>();
        ground = new Texture("ground.png");
        mainMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("mainmusic.mp3"));
        scoreIncrease = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("smw_coin.ogg"));
        wingFlap = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("sfx_wing.ogg"));

        font24= new BitmapFont();
        SCORE = new String();

        groundPos1 = new Vector2(cam.position.x -cam.viewportWidth/2, HIGHEST_GROUND_LIMIT);
        groundPos2 = new Vector2((cam.position.x - cam.viewportWidth/2) + ground.getWidth(),HIGHEST_GROUND_LIMIT);
        startTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

        for(int i=1 ; i<=TUBE_COUNT; i++)
        {

            tubes.add(new Tube(i* (TUBE_SPACING + Tube.TUBE_WIDTH)));
        }
        mainMusic.play();
        mainMusic.setVolume(0.8f);

    }

    @Override
    protected void handleInput() {
        if (Gdx.input.justTouched())
        bird.jump();
        wingFlap.setLooping(false);
        wingFlap.play();
        wingFlap.setVolume(0.1f);
    }




    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        handleInput();

         updateGround();

         bird.update(dt);
        if (TimeUtils.timeSinceNanos(startTime) > 1500000000)
        {
            Score();
            startTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
        }


        fontGenerator();
        SCORE = String.valueOf(k);





        for(int i =0 ; i< tubes.size;i++)
        {
            Tube tube= tubes.get(i);

            if (cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth/2) > tube.getPosTopTube().x + tube.getTopTube().getWidth())
            {
                tube.reposition(tube.getPosTopTube().x + ((Tube.TUBE_WIDTH + TUBE_SPACING) *TUBE_COUNT));
            }
            if(tube.collides(bird.getBounds()))
            {
                cam.position.x = bird.getPosition().x;
                mainMusic.stop();
                gsm.set(new GameOverState(gsm));
                          }

            else
                cam.position.x = bird.getPosition().x +80;

        }
        if (bird.getPosition().y <= ground.getHeight()){
            gsm.set(new GameOverState(gsm));
        }



        cam.update();

    }



    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {

        sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        sb.begin();
        sb.draw(actualGamebg, cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth/2), 0);
        sb.draw(bird.getTexture(), bird.getPosition().x , bird.getPosition().y);
        for(Tube tube: tubes) {

            sb.draw(tube.getTopTube(), tube.getPosTopTube().x, tube.getPosTopTube().y);
            sb.draw(tube.getBottomTube(), tube.getPosBottomTube().x, tube.getPosBottomTube().y);
        }
        sb.draw(ground,groundPos1.x,groundPos1.y);
        sb.draw(ground,groundPos2.x,groundPos2.y);

        font24.draw(sb,SCORE,24,100);
        sb.end();

    }

    /**
     * spritebatches must be drawn in order .The one at the bottommost acts as the top layer.
     */

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        actualGamebg.dispose();
        bird.dispose();
        font24.dispose();
        for(Tube tube: tubes)
        {
            tube.dispose();
        }
        ground.dispose();


        System.out.println("Play State Disposed");

    }




  private void updateGround()
    {
        if (cam.position.x-(cam.viewportWidth/2) > groundPos1.x + ground.getWidth())
        {
            groundPos1.add(ground.getWidth()*2,0);
        }
        if (cam.position.x-(cam.viewportWidth/2) > groundPos2.x + ground.getWidth())
        {
            groundPos2.add(ground.getWidth()*2,0);
        }
    }


    public void Score()
    {
        k++;
        scoreIncrease.play();
        scoreIncrease.setVolume(0.3f);

    }


    public void fontGenerator(){
        FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("bitmapfont/PressStart2P.ttf"));
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter= new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();

        parameter.size=24;
        parameter.color= Color.GOLD;
        parameter.borderColor= Color.GOLDENROD;
        font24= generator.generateFont(parameter);
    }

    public int getK(){return k;}
}
```

Do let me know if you need more info and thanks.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the ttf file and creating a new BitmapFont object every frame. Don't call fontGenerator() in update(). Call it once in the constructor.

Comment: thanks it worked and the game looks much better now .Could you suggest any other optimisation in the code if you see any?